Incorrect vertical glyph alignment(bearing y) with HarfBuzz
I want to render the text as this:

But this is what I got:

here's the full code but for the sake of conciseness I also wrote a small demo in c:
#include "freetype2/ft2build.h"
#include "harfbuzz/hb-ft.h"
#include "hb.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

int main() {
  FT_Library library;
  FT_Init_FreeType(&library);

  FT_Face face;
  FT_New_Face(library, "./LXGWWenKaiLite-Regular.ttf", 0, &face);

  FT_Set_Char_Size(face, 0, 1000, 0, 0);

  hb_font_t *font = hb_ft_font_create(face, NULL);
  hb_ft_font_set_funcs(font);

  hb_buffer_t *buf = hb_buffer_create();

  hb_buffer_add_utf8(buf, "你好——“我说”", -1, 0, -1);
  hb_buffer_guess_segment_properties(buf);
  hb_shape(font, buf, NULL, 0);
  unsigned int glyph_count;
  hb_glyph_info_t *glyph_info = hb_buffer_get_glyph_infos(buf, &glyph_count);
  hb_glyph_position_t *glyph_pos =
      hb_buffer_get_glyph_positions(buf, &glyph_count);

  hb_position_t cursor_x = 0;
  hb_position_t cursor_y = 0;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < glyph_count; i++) {
    hb_codepoint_t glyphid = glyph_info[i].codepoint;
    hb_position_t x_offset = glyph_pos[i].x_offset;
    hb_position_t y_offset = glyph_pos[i].y_offset;
    hb_position_t x_advance = glyph_pos[i].x_advance;
    hb_position_t y_advance = glyph_pos[i].y_advance;
    printf("offset: (%d, %d), advance: (%d, %d)\n", x_offset, y_offset,
           x_advance, y_advance);
    /* draw_glyph(glyphid, cursor_x + x_offset, cursor_y + y_offset); */

    cursor_x += x_advance;
    cursor_y += y_advance;
  }
}

And I got this:
offset: (0, 0), advance: (1000, 0)
offset: (0, 0), advance: (1000, 0)
offset: (0, 0), advance: (1000, 0)
offset: (0, 0), advance: (1000, 0)
offset: (0, 0), advance: (350, 0)
offset: (0, 0), advance: (1000, 0)
offset: (0, 0), advance: (1000, 0)
offset: (0, 0), advance: (350, 0)

Which is not what I want as offset is always 0, but in the string "你好——“我说”", I expect the "——" to be centered, which obviously isn't here.
Is it I'm getting something wrong or that harfbuzz doesn't solve the bearing y for me?

I don't think I can answer this question, but there are several other metrics for glyph rendering not exposed here that are in freetype2 https://freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/glyphs-3.html  I'm not sure if harfbuzz is supposed to fix this for you anyway though, since looking at harfbuzz's documentation, it doesn't even mention these.  I would check the equivalent data in freetype, it might not answer  your question, but maybe it will help you diagnose.

Thanks, Krupip. I'm starting to figure out that harfbuzz doesn't take care of bearingX & bearingY inside a glyph. But I still have trouble to have the correct layout for texts. I'm reading codes from working examples for now.
